# Elasticsearch-6.24 logstash-6.2.4 migration error from MySQL to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Hi please have a look at below issue. I am clueless how to fix this issue.
I've downloaded ElasticSrearch -6.2.4 and Logstash - 6.2.4 on the window machine.
I'm trying to import data from MySQL to ElasticSearch using LogStash. but I'm getting the below error :

C:\logstash-6.2.4\bin>logstash -f logstash.conf

Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Apache

here are the steps I'm following:

first I started the ElasticSearch which is running perfectly on the port 9200.
then I've added the below Scripts in logstash.yml which has all the migration instructions.

```
# ------------ MySQL to ElasticSearch -------------

    input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySQL_ElasticSearch_Demo"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "root"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.46/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM user"
    }
  }
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
    "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
    "index" => "users"
    "document_type" => "usersData"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to run the logstash via command prompt using below command:

C:\logstash-6.2.4\bin>logstash -f logstash.conf

**Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Apache**

===> any help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of java is on your machine?

Comment: i'm using java 1.8.

Comment: These are usually config errors but hard to say what is misconfigured without seeing the full trace of the error